# Making a webserver using jsp and java

Tags: iphone, jsp

Using Google App Engine SDK:
webpage: http://hwsejk.appspot.com/

I'm trying to make a web server using java and jsp (it is a web server for an iPhone application). I don't know a lot about java so I'm having a lot of troubles trying to construct a server by myself. For now, I have tried implementing cookie, database, and some other methods. Now that I've given you basic information about my web server, I have a few questions to ask.

Is it the right approach to use java and jsp to make a web server like this? the java servlets get and send user inputs to different jsp pages, which contain some HTML and java code. But I've found some posts here that it's a bad practice to use jsp like this. I don't know how else I can make webpages. Could anyone please recommend the right approach to make a web server (like the one linked above)? I would love to know if there is some kind of a template that I can take a look at.

Answer (score 0):

What you are making doesnt seem to be a "server" at all but rather a "web application" or "web site". The former implies you are creating a piece of sfotware to implement a specific protocol like `HTTP`, `FTP`, etc. while the latter is making a series of web pages or and application that runs on server.

You can create a web application in any number of languages, not just Java. From the screenshot you shared i would think that using Rails (Ruby), Django (Paython), or Symfony2 (PHP) would probably get you up and running pretty fast as it looks like you dont need much more than some basic model scaffolding with a pretty face.

If you are familiar with Java you might also want to try the [Play!](http://www.playframework.org/) framework...

Comment: Yes, the right terminology is "web application." I would like to stick to java because that's the language that my school primarily uses. What exactly is a "framework?" how is it different from using a Google App Engine SDK?

Comment: Well i havent used GAE so i cant comment specifically. But in general terms GAE is a platform of sorts like `LAMP` is platform, there are specifics to working in that environment with what languages and types of resources are supported and in this case youd probably have to use the SDK to utilize certain things. An application framework is like a library to build an application on. It attempts to cover the basic plumbing any application needs so that a developer doesnt need to write a new implementation everytime he creates an application.